# How make two <ul> facing each other asp.net

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net

I want placed my list facing each other like this

```
home          log in
about         register
```

I can do it only like this

```
home
about
log in
register
```

This is my code

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="banner"></div>
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul id="nav">
            <li style="text-align: left">
                <a href="~/Default.aspx" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700; text-align: left">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="auto-style1"> 
                    <a href="#">Reviews</a>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li style="text-align: left">
                        <a href="#">Books</a>
                    </li>
                    <li style="text-align: left">
                        <a href="#">Book shops</a>
                    </li>
                    <li style="text-align: left">
                        <a href="#">Famous Books</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li style="text-align: left">
                <a href="#">Shop</a>
            </li>
            <li style="text-align: left">
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content_area">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>All Rights reserved.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="log">
    <ul id="form_log">
        <li style="text-align: right">
            <a href="~/Default.aspx" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700; text-align: left">Log in</a>
        </li>
        <li style="text-align: right">
            <a href="~/Default.aspx" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700; text-align: left">Register</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, help me) I think it easy for you, guys)

Comment: This is purely down to styling. What have you tried in your CSS?

Comment: Side-note: You have an extra closing `</div>` just before `<div id="log">` that you need to remove.

Answer (score 0):

This is purely down to styling of the lists and divs. As an example (using floats):

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/j8eqrtnk/

```
ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#wrapper{
    float: left;
}
#log{
    float: right;
}
```

This will float the entire `#wrapper` div to the left side of the page and the `#log` menu to the right of the page.

Another option would be to absolutely position the menu on the top right. This will however allow the left and right area to overlap when the screen gets very narrow:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/j8eqrtnk/1/

```
ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#log{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 10px;
}
```

note your HTML had an extra closing `</div>` you need to remove:

```
</div>
</div>         <==== remove this
<div id="log">
```

Comment: It will be work if I use one ul list or can use two ul lists, one for navigation and one for log?

Comment: @user3182349: Yes you can lay it out like that with one list as well. If you can update my JSFiddle with the menu options you want, I will be happy to show you.

Answer (score 0):

Check This JSfiddle :-  http://jsfiddle.net/en0ysaym/

```
<div id="navcontainer">
     <ul id="navlist">
         <li id="active"><a href="#" id="current">Item one</a> 
           <ul id="subnavlist">
             <li id="subactive"><a href="#" id="subcurrent">Item Two</a></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
     </ul>
  <ul id="navlist">
      <li><a href="#">Item three</a>
         <ul id="subnavlist">
            <li id="subactive"><a href="#" id="subcurrent">Item Four</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item Five</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```